# how to add courtesy copies in Matlab

Tags: matlab, smtp

I'd like to cc & bcc in matlab without any external components (File Ex has a solution that has a .jar file).  Any references to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I thought, it involves Java, and it's not entirely straightforward, thanks to Matlab's love-hate relationship with Java.

Looking at ML's `sendmail()` function, the key line is:

```
 msg.addRecipient(getRecipientTypeTo(msg), getInternetAddress(to{i}));
```

where `getRecipientTypeTo()` is a function to get a static class instance from Java for the recipient type:

```
function recipientTypeTo = getRecipientTypeTo(msg)
%getRecipientTypeTo Return the static RecipientType.TO.

% Get the class loader for the Message class.
cl = msg.getClass.getClassLoader;
% Returns a Class object pointing to RecipientType using that ClassLoader.
rt = java.lang.Class.forName('javax.mail.Message$RecipientType', false, cl);
% Returns a Field object pointint to TO.
field = rt.getField('TO');
% Gets the static instance of TO.
recipientTypeTo = field.get([]);
```

So, modify the static one is getting (CC and BCC are supported, entirely unsurprisingly), and use `addRecipient()`.

Comment: could you please extend this to feature example bcc/cc email addresses? I'm not as familiar with Java, I don't see how to add the bcc/cc fields from this.